# What is this Keep the license and copyright notice included in Bootstrap’s CSS and JavaScript files when you use them in your works?

Tags: python, licensing

I have developed a website using Django and I have used getbootstrap4.3 in my website. [On the official website](https://getbootstrap.com), they have [stated like this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/about/license/):

> ###### It requires you to:
>
> - Keep the license and copyright notice included in Bootstrap’s CSS and JavaScript files when you use them in your works

I really don't understand this, what is a copyright notice, and where I should include it?

Comment: Did you look at the Bootstrap’s CSS and JavaScript files source code, at the top of the files? e.g. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/45d26de72817b295c5f94c8426354fd5b7d0a1f9/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css#L2 and https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/45d26de72817b295c5f94c8426354fd5b7d0a1f9/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js#L2

Answer (score 2):

What the FAQ entry is referring to are comment blocks like this one

> ```
> /*!
>  * Bootstrap v5.0.2 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
>  * Copyright 2011-2021 The Bootstrap Authors (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/graphs/contributors)
>  * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
>  */
> ```

and it is telling you that you must not delete them from your copy of Bootstrap.

The copyright notice is the line starting with the word "Copyright".

The license that allows you to use the Bootstrap files (the MIT license) has as one of its few conditions that you must keep the copyright and licensing information intact.

Comment: +1. That said: one may *add* further lines to the copyright notice, e.g. your own authorship when one modifies the file. But making changes still requires to keep this acknowledgement of the original authorship in its entirety, no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

> I really don't understand this, what is a copyright notice [?]

The copyright notice is the notice given by the original authors and/or copyright holders.

Written to give anyone (potentially including you) notice about the copyright.

See as well the dictionary or encyclopedia of your choice.

If you're concerned about legal matters, contact a lawyer on your behalf, they should be able to educate you about the international meaning as well about the differences that apply to you as human locally where you are.

> where I should include it?

Please read the sentence again:

> Keep the license and copyright notice included in Bootstrap’s CSS and JavaScript files when you use them in your works.

You should keep the already included notice in Bootstrap’s CSS and JavaScript files when you *use* them in your works.

It is written there all verbatim.

If you're concerned about the legal meaning of any of these words incl. *"included"* please contact a lawyer on your behalf. Lawyers are normally educated well enough that they next to legal matters can also help with reading texts as they need to do that a lot.

If you're still in education, another idea might be to talk with your tutor or professor about how to understand sentences like these.

Also the Bootstraps' project did made this as an FAQ, so the information you can find on that page is meant to make it easier for you - not more complicated.